# Input multiple string in list - python

Tags: python, string, list, input

Hello so im new on python, i want to know how to do multiple string input on list. I already try to append the input to the list, but it doesn't give me expected output. Here is the source code:

```
test=[]
input1=input("Enter multiple strings: ")
splitinput1=input1.split()
for x in range(len(splitinput1)):
    test.append(splitinput1)
print(test)
print(len(test))
```

And the output is not what i expected:

```
Enter multiple strings:  A B C
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
3
```

However, when i change to `print(splitinput1)`, it give me expected output:

```
Enter multiple strings:  A B C
['A', 'B', 'C']
3
```

So how to make the output like `print(splitinput1)` while use `print(test)` and whats missing on my code? Thankyou.

Comment: You're doing a lot of extra steps and duplicating the list unintentionally with that `for` loop.  Just do `test = input("Enter multiple strings: ").split()`.

Comment: If you really want to play with `for` loops, the code you want is `for x in splitinput1: test.append(x)`.  You don't want to append all of `splitinput1` to `test` three times, you want to append each of the three items individually.  (This `for` loop is also the same as `test.extend(splitinput1)`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have slight error in your code. Do this:

```
test=[]
input1=input("Enter multiple strings: ")
splitinput1=input1.split()
for x in splitinput1:
   test.append(x)
print(test)
print(len(test))
```

Comment: no need for the for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
strings = input("Enter multiple strings: ")
test = strings.split()
print(test)
print(len(test))
```

Comment: Your solution for the `['A', 'B', 'C']` is right sir, but the `print(len(test))` shows 1. So when i want to `print(test[2])` it give me `IndexError: list index out of range`. So @BishwashK is more correct

Comment: ````test.append(strings.split())```` creates a list inside a list => [['a', 'b', 'c']]. so len() gives a result of 1. better to use: ````test = strings.split()````. this also makes the first line of the code redundant: remove test = []. then the length of the list will be given correctly.